# How can I ensure that only one process is running a function in python multiprocess?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that is invoked by potentially multiple processes created with multiprocessing. I want to ensure not serialization, but single execution by the original process, that is only the main process will perform some logic, and the others will do nothing.

One option is to use a RLock with blocking=False, but this does not guarantee that the main process will perform the execution. I don't want to differentiate on current_process().name because it just doesn't feel right, and as far as I understand the name is arbitrary and not necessarily unique anyway.

Is there a more elegant way to ensure this? In MPI I used to do it with the id.

Comment: what do you think should happen, when non-main process tries to execute that function? It would receive some exception?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the problem -- why do the child processes include the code and permission to call the function at all?  A simply flag at creation should turn this off.  Better yet, do not spawn the children with the calling code at all.

Comment: @Prune because it was developed by people who should not develop.

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky do nothing and just return

Comment: Oh ... you're stuck with upgrading legacy code, but you cannot re-factor that code?  My condolences.

Comment: Now ... what *can* you change?  I assume that you can change the main; how much control do you get over the function? Do you have any over the child processes?  One simple way would be to spawn each child with a flag that it would then propagate to the function, giving an explicit identification to the function.